# CodeDeploy giving a Ruby error when I try to deploy

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-code-deploy

appspec.yml:

```
version: 0.0
os: linux
files:
  - source: /
    destination: /var/ingester
permissions:
  - object: /var
    pattern: ingester
    owner: ubuntu
    group: ubuntu
    type:
      - directory
  - object: /var/ingester
    owner: ubuntu
    group: ubuntu
hooks:
  ApplicationStart:
    - location: deployment/start.sh
      runas: ubuntu
```

Codedeploy gets to BeforeInstall and then errors with:

> ERROR [codedeploy-agent(2735)]: InstanceAgent::Plugins::CodeDeployPlugin::CommandPoller: Error during perform: TypeError - no implicit conversion of String into Integer - /opt/codedeploy-agent/lib/instance_agent/plugins/codedeploy/application_specification/application_specification.rb:49:in `[]'

It *looks* as though this is related to the parsing of the YAML, but I can't figure out what it's trying (and failing) to convert to an integer.

Can anyone spot what's going wrong here?

Comment: Which version of the codedeploy agent are you using? Have you tried updating it to the latest version?

Comment: @Castrohenge It's being installed on the EC2 box's spinning up, so it should be the latest version already.

Comment: Can you check appspec.yml in /opt/codedeploy-agent/deployment-root/<deployment_group_id>/<deployment_id>/ ? Is this same as you posted above ? Error suggests that `files` section is treated as hash instead an array of hashes. I suspect `-` is missing before `source:` in appspec.yml on instance.

Comment: @Ravi You're exactly right, thank you. The version being deployed didn't match the version I'd been staring at; replacing the appspec.yml with the version I had locally fixed the issue. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a hint from Ravi (see OP comments), I checked the appspec.yml on the EC2 box and it appeared to be an old copy, missing the hyphen before the `source:` in the YAML. Thus, Ruby interpreted it as a hash instead of an array.